# Enabling Direct3D on XP using Older NVidia cards

Tags: windows-xp, directx, direct3d

I'm having a really hard time figuring this one out and could use some advice:

I have 5 machines with XP SP3 installed all using the same setup.  They all have NVidia 8600 GT video cards, DirectX 9c and the latest drivers and windows updates.

2 machines have Direct3D enabled and dxdiag recognizes the video RAM and DDI version.  The other 3 machines don't have the ability to enable Direct 3D and dxdiag doesn't see the video RAM or the DDI version.

I've tried rolling the driver back to one that explicitly supports direct3d.  I've tried installing the unsupported directx 10 package.  I've tried uninstalling .Net updates.  I've enabled/disabled options within the Windows and NVidia GUIs.  I've rebooted once or twice between each change.  And none of it has fixed it.

I know it's a really old video card, but that's not the point.  The point is getting Direct3d enabled on Windows XP using directx 9c using NVidia video card and drivers and I can't figure out why it's working like it is.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the two machines where it works and the others where it doesn't could be the BIOS.  You may need to change the BIOS settings or flash the BIOS to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing I can do at this point is to format and re-install XP on the machines that don't work, testing the video card after every Windows Update and driver install.  It's the only way I can think of to effectively figure out the root of the issue.